# RPi irresponsive ssh access to LAN

Tags: networking, ssh

I have the following setup at home:

- 3 RPis connected to router via ethernet. They have more than enough power supplies and are headless.

  - RPi #1 (very old model) runs pihole and acts as DHCP server.
  - RPi #2 (very old model) runs some lightweight web services.
  - RPi #3 (model 4) runs some heavier web services.
- IP addresses are static as configured in RPi #1's pihole DHCP server. The router's DHCP server is switched off accordingly.

The issue I've been having for a couple of months is the following: the third RPi becomes irresponsive often and seems to *freeze* SSH access to any of the other RPis. *Freeze* as in I can ping any of the RPis fine but cannot ssh into any of them—terminal gets stuck without showing any output. RPi #3's web services become inaccessible, but the other two RPi's web services are working fine and are accessible, yet I cannot ssh into them. I pull the plug on RPi #3 and I can then ssh into the other two RPis fine. Interestingly, even when everything is frozen, I can use WireGuard on RPi #3 fine, so this RPi hasn't crashed and it has a network connection, even though all web services are seemingly down.

I use Mac OS over wifi to connect to the RPis.

I also activated the watchdog for the problematic RPi #3 but no luck.

Any ideas?

Comment: You should edit into the question: 1) How the Pi addresses are set (static or DHCP); if static, what arrangements you have made *on the router* to support this. 2) What you are connecting from -- the OS, how it receives an address, and whether this is via wifi or ethernet.

Comment: Thank you @goldilocks, edited with more info.

Answer (score 1):

> The router's DHCP server is switched off accordingly

You should explicitly add the static assignments to the router's configuration if possible.  Otherwise, there is the possibility of the addresses to half stop working -- a node can pass traffic back and forth through the router, **but the router does not pass traffic from wifi nodes to the ethernet nodes** because it has no routing table entry for them<sup>1</sup> -- I'm guessing by "freeze" you mean attempts to reach them just time out as if nothing is there (vs. the request immediately being refused).

What you describe fits that scenario; Pi #3 is still working in the sense that wireguard tunnels are fine (because it can still pass traffic back and forth to the internet through the router, presuming that's where those tunnels go), and it can still communicate with the other Pi's because they are all on the ethernet segment, which functions like a [switch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_switch).  But communication between wifi nodes and ethernet nodes must be forwarded by the router.

You could confirm this by running wireshark promiscuously on one of the ethernet nodes; packets from wifi addresses will simply stop appearing.<sup>2</sup>

> seems to freeze SSH access to any of the other RPis ... I pull the plug on RPi #3 and I can then ssh into the other two RPis fine

That it *seems* to be so is fine, **but this is not really possible** (ie., #3 cannot cause such a freeze) unless #3 has launched some kind of DOS attack on the other two.  That would show up very clearly in wireshark, but it is pretty unlikely -- even if there were malware or something in play, I don't think one Pi could effect this on two others simultaneously.

---

1. "But," you say, "it was working 10 minutes ago!"  Keep in mind the routing table is periodically updated on the basis of [ARP requests](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_Resolution_Protocol).  Why that should go wrong I'm not sure, but I have seen this happen.  It could be, eg., that the router simply does not make such requests about addresses that are not in its list of active leases **or static assignments**. Hence the need for such.
2. That pings go through I don't have an explanation for, but ICMP is a distinct protocol from ARP or TCP and may get effectively broadcast across all the router's interfaces.

Comment: Sweet, I'm gonna add the static addresses in the router as well and see what happens.

I've been switching off & on #3 to fix this issue for a couple of months! No idea what could be going on, but #3 shouldn't interact with the other two at all (in regard to the DOS suggestion).

Comment: Sadly, this didn't work. More info: when the network _freezes_, I need to power cycle #3 for all RPis to respond to ssh again. I tried power cycling the others and, even when they booted up again, I couldn't ssh any of them, but I could access the web services in #1 and #2. Puzzling.

Comment: What I mean by frozen ssh is that the terminal gets stuck, doesn't explicitly timeout or print anything, and doesn't respond to the usual escape sequence. I have to quit the terminal by closing it.

Comment: What happens when you try to connect againt with ssh's verbosity increased (`-v` = some, `-vv`= more)?.  Wireshark might be very useful here although that could require some previous experience.  Also would be good if you could hotplug a screen and keyboard to see what's going on when the freeze happens.

Comment: This is the output of `ssh -vvv pi@<RPi #3's IP>`: https://pastebin.com/swjNaNy9. It gets stuck there forever until I quit the terminal.

(Note that the RPis are set up to accept ssh connections with ssh key only, without password prompting.)

Debug logs are similar for the other RPi's as well.

Comment: Did you read the last line? That will generally cause significant problems -- except googling around implies it may not mean what it looks like it means, and may or may not be the cause of your problem, but you do need to search "ssh pledge filesystem full" and have a look a some of the (supposed) solutions/assertions and investigate them (eg., that permissions on the local host keys doesn't allow them to be updated).  Also a heads up that there seems to be a "filesystem full" and a distinct "file system full" >_<

Comment: OTOH It looks a lot like a red herring.  You should save the output of `-vv` for a successful login and disconnect, then diff/compare that to when the problem occurs.

Comment: Yes, I googled around that last message, and my (naive) conclusion was that it didn't indicate a problem on its own. This is a ssh debug output for a successful login: https://pastebin.com/TnjF2H3q. Interestingly, it's exactly the same but it just keeps going!

Comment: I'm trying out the hacky solution of rebooting RPi #3 on a daily basis, given that it seems to stay stable for that amount of time.

Comment: There does seem to be some fussing with host keys there, since these are all on the same LAN you might want to set `UserKnownHostsFile /dev/null` for those connections.

Comment: I'll try that next time things freeze (although with the scheduled daily reboot perhaps there won't be a next time!).

Comment: Well, it's being running perfectly for four days with an automated daily reboot. Puzzling!